# Limit theorem of extreme values

Tags: statistics, probability-limit-theorems, order-statistics

What does it mean for a cumulative density function of a standardized variable to tend to a limiting value? This is main part of the problem I don't understand too well. Below is the problem I am trying to solve, and my current progress in doing so:

**Problem**

> Let $U_1,\dots,U_n$ be independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$, and let $U_{(n)}$ be the maximum. Find the cdf of $U_{(n)}$ and a standardized $U_{(n)}$, and show that the cdf of the standardized variable tends to a limiting value.

**Solution so far**

The density function of a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ is $f(x) = 1$ and the cdf is $F(x) = x$ for $x \in [0,1]$, so for $U_{(n)}$, the density function is
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x) = \frac{n!}{(n-1)!(n-n)!}f(x)F^{n-1}(x)[1-F(x)]^{n-n} = nx^{n-1},
\end{equation*}
and the cdf is
\begin{equation*}
F_n(x) = \int_0^x nt^{n-1}\;dt = x^n.
\end{equation*}
Let $S_n = \frac{U_{(n)} - E(U_{(n)})}{\sqrt{Var(U_{(n)})}}$ be the standardized variable of $U_{(n)}$.
\begin{equation}
E(U_{(n)}) = \int_0^1xnx^{n-1}\;dx = \frac{n}{n+1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E(U_{(n)}^2) = \int_0^1x^2nx^{n-1}\;dx = \frac{n}{n+2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Var(U_{(n)}) = E(U_{(n)}^2)- E(U_{(n)})^2 = \frac{n}{n+2}-\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{n}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
S_n = -\sqrt{n(n+2)} + \frac{(n+1)\sqrt{n+2}}{\sqrt{n}}U_{(n)}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E(S_n) = 0, \qquad Var(S_n) = 1
\end{equation}

**Idea?**

Should I be finding the moment generating function of $U_{(n)}$ and then use it to find the moment generating function of $S$, $M_S(t)$, then take $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_S(t)$ and see if the result matches any of the moment generating functions for the most common distributions?

Comment: Seems like you're making it too complicated.  The CDF is easy:  $P\{U_{(n)} \le x\} = P\{U_i \le x \forall i\}$.  Do you know about Beta distributions?  This would be helpful for the rest.  For the limit, you can show pointwise convergence at points of continuity directly.  I suspect that is what is expected of you.

Comment: Intuitively I feel like the limiting value should be 1, but probability is not my strong point. Can someone confirm or correct my reasoning?: We are selecting the maximum of $n$ random variables uniformly chosen from the interval [0,1]. If we take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity, the probability of *none* of the points being in some interval $[1-\epsilon,1]$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ should shrink to zero.

Comment: The maximum indeed converges in distribution to 1.  However, the question asks about the convergence of the standardized distributions.

Comment: Oh right >.< Sorry for the obvious remark, then.

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn The only other time I have seen the subscript enclosed in parenthesis, i.e. $X_{(i)}$, is for order statistics, where my texbook has a theorem stating that the density of $X_{(i)}$, the $i$-th order statistic is
\begin{equation}
f_k(x) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}f(x)F^{k-1}[1-F(x)]^{n-k}
\end{equation}
I'm not familiar with the Beta distribution, but I will look it up.

Comment: Can you show my what you mean by showing pointwise convergence at points of continuity directly? I have only seen pointwise convergence when looking at sequences of function in real analysis for uniform convergence.

Comment: $F_n$ converges to $F$ in distribution iff $F_n(x)$ converges to $F(x)$ at each x where $F$ is continuous.  (You may take this as a definition.)  Once you figure out your standardized CDF's, the limit should be clear.

Comment: As to the *meaning* that you ask about, let $F_n(x)$ be the cdf of the normalized distribution. One wants to show that for any $x$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x)$ exists.

Comment: Call your normalized rv $S_n$. We want $\Pr(S_n\le s)$. This is the probability that $U_{(n)} \le \sigma_n s +\mu_n$, which is $(\sigma_n s +\mu_n)^n$. Now let $n\to\infty$. When I do calculations, having a bit of trouble, but it looks as if one gets an exponential out of it.

Comment: The limit does exist and is interesting.  I have never seen this before.

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn the context I excluded from the problem that prefaces what I wrote is "In addition to limit theorems that deal with sums, there are limit theorems that deal with extreme values such as maxima or minima. Here is an example."

Comment: @AndréNicolas how did you get $(\sigma_ns + \mu_n)^n$? Is this from multiplying $\sigma_ns + \mu_n$ for each of the $n$ independent copies of $U_i$?

Comment: $S_n=\frac{U_{(n)}-\mu_n}{\sigma_n}$. So $S_n\le s$ if and only if $U_{(n)}\le \sigma_n x+\mu_n$. But recall that the cdf of $U_{(n)}$ is $x^n$. So it is not **directly** from multiplying, since we already had the cdf of $U_{(n)}$. But of course that is how we obtained the cdf, at least if one does it the right way, not quoting the general formula.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah, sorry I didn't make that connection. Thank you.

Comment: The limit looked nasty so I plugged into wolfram and it spat out $e^{-1+x}$. Do we not care about the growth of this as $x$ becomes large, but instead only care about the fact that it exists for every $x$?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n-%3Einf+%28%28sqrt%28n%29x%29%2F%28%28n%2B1%29%28sqrt%28n%2B2%29%29%29+%2B+%28n%29%2F%28n%2B1%29%29^n
note that the link excludes the "^n"

Comment: Yes, I got that too, by hand. It is pretty easy, just take a $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$ "outside". It has limit $e^{-1}$. The inside stuff is a close enough relative of (1+x/n)^n$.

Comment: That is significantly simpler than how wolfram showed evaluating the limit. Thank you for the help, both of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mu_n$ be the mean of $S_n$, and $\sigma_n$ its standard deviation. Then $\Pr(S_n \le s)=\Pr(U_{(n)}\le \sigma_n s+\mu_n)$. This is $(\sigma_n s+\mu_n)^n$. 
Now we calculate. A little manipulation shows that
$$(\sigma_n s+\mu_n)^n=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \left(1+\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+2}}\right)^n.$$
The term $\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+2}$ behaves essentially like $n$, more precisely like $n+1$, but it doesn't matter. The limit is $e^{-1}e^s$.

**Added:** Please note the comment by Stephen Herschkorn that the limit of the cdf is given by the above expression only for a certain range of values of $s$, since 
$\Pr(U_{(n)}\le \sigma_n s+\mu_n)=(\sigma_n s+\mu_n)^n$ only when $0\le \sigma_n s+\mu_n\le 1$.