# A problem from Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

This problem is from Ch. 5, Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis, 3rd edition, stated as follows,

---

In addition to limit theorems that deal with sums, there are limit theorems that deal with extreme values such as maxima or minima. Here is an example. Let $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ be independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$, and let $U_{(n)}$ be the maximum. Find the cdf of $U_{(n)}$ and a standardized $U_{(n)}$, and show that the cdf of the standardized variable tends to a limiting value.

---

Below is my derivation. The cdf of $U_{(n)}$ is as follows,
$$
F_{(n)} = \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        x^n, & \text{if } x \in [0,1]\\
        0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right\}
$$
and pdf
$$
f_{(n)} = \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        nx^{n-1}, & \text{if } x \in [0,1]\\
        0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right\}
$$
With pdf we can calculate mean and variance, which is
$$
E(U_{(n)}) = \frac{n}{n+1}, \text{Var}(U_{(n)}) = \frac{n}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}
$$
The standardized variable $Z_n$ is
$$
Z_{n} = \frac{U_{(n)}-\frac{n}{n+1}}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}}}
$$

---

However, the key is quite different from mine. The standardized variable it gives is $Z_n = n(U_{(n)}-1)$. Did I miss something? Many thanks!

Comment: What does standardization means in the context of uniform distribution? There most be something there in your textbook that talks about that.

Comment: The first problems was asked before in MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/448522/121671). As for the *normalization* in the key, Henry's answers addresses that.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The standardization indeed has not to be done in this way. Your link is helpful. For both ways of standardization, a constant can be acquired but the one from the key is neater.

Answer (score 2):

$U_{(n)}$ has a Beta$(n,1)$ distribution, sometimes called a *standard power function*. This gives the mean and variance you have stated.

The distribution of $n(1-U_{(n)})$ converges in distribution to an exponential distribution with rate $1$ so with mean and variance and standard deviation each $1$, and thus $n(U_{(n)}-1)$ converges in distribution to its negative.

Relocating this to have mean $0$ is possible but a slightly unusual thing to do for an exponential distribution. If you did, you would in effect be saying that the distribution of the standardised value of $U_{(n)}$ you stated has a limiting distribution with CDF $$F(x) = \min(e^{x-1},1)$$ the same as $1-Y$ where $Y\sim Exp(1)$.